# Is there any good, free site statistics software?

Tags: php, statistics

I mean something like google analytics, but that I can host it myself. Preferrably written in javascript + php.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track Page Views using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227444/track-page-views-using-php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several analytics tools avaiable (free):

- [Piwik](http://www.phpmyvisites.us/) (my advice)
- [SlimStat](http://slimstat.net/)
- [TraceWatch](http://www.tracewatch.com/)
- [CrawlTrack](http://www.crawltrack.net/)
- [Syndikut - Visitors-online](http://www.sharewareconnection.com/syndikut-visitors-online.htm)
- [CPU Load Reader](http://code.blitzaffe.com/pages/phpclasses/files/cpu_load_reader_52-15)

Answer (score 8):

I myself love [Piwik.](http://piwik.org/) It seems to meet your criteria too.

Answer (score 2):

Piwik is a good call.

Woopra is also good.

But personally, i don't see anything wrong with good old Google analytics.
We use it for all our clients where I work.
All of our clients sites cost £20k+, and they aren't bothered by using using what is essentially a free service.
We just integrate the Google analytics data into their admin area on their sites, so they don't need to log into a separate place to view their analytics.